# NHibernate LINQ BIGINT casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, casting, max

I am trying to understand the NHibernate SQL output for this entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long Number { get; set; }
}
```

When I write:

```
var maxNumber = s.Query<Person>().Max(p => p.Number);
```

The generated SQL looks as follows:

```
select cast(max(person0_.Number) as BIGINT) as col_0_0_ from Person person0_
```

**Why is the cast needed if the `Number` column is `bigint` anyway?**

I am using NHibernate 3.2, SQL Server 2008 R2, mapping defined as follows:

```
<class name="NhMappingTest.Person, NhMappingTest">
      <id name="Id"><generator class="increment" /></id>
      <property name="Number" />
</class>
```

Comment: Is it the same if you drop `type="System.Int64, mscorlib"` from your mapping?

Comment: @Rippo: yes, I added that later to see if it will change anything. I also created the DB schema using NHibernate before I added this, and column was created as `bigint`. Also, `not-null` doesn't seem to affect this. I'll simplify it to my first repro version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *needed*. It's an implementation detail:

```
protected HqlTreeNode VisitNhMax(NhMaxExpression expression)
{
    return _hqlTreeBuilder.Cast(
        _hqlTreeBuilder.Max(
            VisitExpression(expression.Expression).AsExpression()), 
            expression.Type);
}
```

So, the code is blindingly casting the result.

Comment: Ok, since it most likely doesn't affect performance at the server side, I am happy with that. I just wanted to check if this was a potential bug, since the query also failed to execute in some other aspects. Thanks for taking the time to check the source code.